# How to add missing value in a case statement or if value does not exist do an alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that updates every 5 minutes with data showing number of customers waiting per category (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

The table I have is

```
    |waiting in seconds | Category |
    |:------------------|:---------:|
    |125                |    0      |
    |240                |    1      |
    |350                |    2      |
    |100                |    3      |
    |12                 |    4      |
    |125                |    5      |
```

Sometimes there wont be any person waiting in any of the categories, so I want to find a way that If there is no one in any of the category, it should say 'Category X', 0 minutes

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT CAST(001 AS INT) AS SITEID, 
CASE
    WHEN Category = 0 THEN CAST('Category 0' AS NVARCHAR(40))
    WHEN Category = 1 THEN CAST('Category 1' AS NVARCHAR(40))
    WHEN Category = 2 THEN CAST('Category 2' AS NVARCHAR(40))
    WHEN Category = 3 THEN CAST('Category 3' AS NVARCHAR(40))
    WHEN Category = 4 THEN CAST('Category 4' AS NVARCHAR(40))
    WHEN Category = 5 THEN CAST('Category 5' AS NVARCHAR(40))
END AS CurrentCustomers,
CASE
    WHEN waiting in seconds = 0 OR waiting in seconds IS NULL THEN '0 Minutes'
    WHEN waiting in seconds = 1 THEN  '1 Second'    
    WHEN waiting in seconds < 3600 THEN CAST((waiting in seconds / 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
    ELSE 'ERROR'
END AS WatingTime,
```

I want to get some advice on how I could add that into my query. do I need to add an IIF statement? Currently if there is no one in Category 0 that line does not come across.

Would appreciate some guidance

Comment: What is WAIT_BLENDED_S?

Comment: sorry, I updated that. It is 'waiting in seconds'

Comment: *Presumably* you have a `Category` table, so have that in your `FROM` and then `LEFT JOIN` to whatever table you have above; then you will always have all the rows for each of your categories.

Comment: And why not just have `concat('Category ', Category)` instead of that case expression?

Comment: I only have read access to the database, and using ADF to pull it across & pass across to an API. so no option at to have an extra table.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, incl 0 and > 2600 values. And also _specify_ the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: Seems like `CAST(001 AS INT) AS SITEID` can simply be `CAST(1 AS INT) AS SITEID`

Comment: Did you mean `waiting in seconds` to be `[waiting in seconds]` here? - one reason I dislike whitespace in column names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define a `Categories` table or inline the equivalent category enumeration in a `VALUES` construct. That could then be `LEFT JOIN`ed with your actual data. If a row is absent, the `[waiting in seconds]` values would be `NULL` in the results, for which you already have a `CASE ... WHEN` branch.

```
SELECT
    CAST(001 AS INT) AS SITEID,
    C.Name AS CurrentCustomers,
    CASE
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] = 0 OR W.[waiting in seconds] IS NULL THEN '0 Minutes'
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] = 1 THEN  '1 Second'    
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] < 3600 THEN CAST((W.[waiting in seconds] / 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS WatingTime
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'Category 1'),
        (2, 'Category 2'),
        (3, 'Category 3'),
        (4, 'Category 4'),
        (5, 'Category 5'),
        (6, 'Category 6')
) C(Id, Name)
LEFT JOIN Waiting W
    ON W.Category = C.Id
ORDER BY C.Id
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    CAST(001 AS INT) AS SITEID,
    C.Name AS CurrentCustomers,
    CASE
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] = 0 OR W.[waiting in seconds] IS NULL THEN '0 Minutes'
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] = 1 THEN  '1 Second'    
        WHEN W.[waiting in seconds] < 3600 THEN CAST((W.[waiting in seconds] / 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS WatingTime
FROM Categories C
LEFT JOIN Waiting W
    ON W.Category = C.Id
ORDER BY C.Id
```

This can also be done using a #Categories temp table, if you only have read access to the database.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zZAib2x2) for a demo that shows both approaches.